about change of basis matrix and matix similarity
so lets say A,B are similar matrices and P is a change of basis matrix from A to B.
so by matrix similarity $A = PAP^{-1}$
is the order of P and P^-1 important? ($P^{-1}AP = PAP^{-1}$)
if yes what is the correct order?
in my teacher's notes he showed it both ways and didn't really define the direction of P (he probably said it while showing it but i was absent from that lesson and i am going through the notes now), i did try to look for an answer on this and read a few definitions from wikipedia and other sources but pretty much everywhere i looked they use a different syntax for change of basis matrix and that got me even more confused about it.
thanks

I think a good answer would be yes and no. Suppose your matrix has coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$ (it does not matter).
If you only want to say that there exists a $P \in GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ such that $A = P^{-1}BP$, then the order does not matter. Why ? Simply because $P$ is invertible. Therefore, you can find $Q \in GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ such that $B = Q^{-1}AQ$ which is rewritten as $A = QBQ^{-1}$. Such a $Q$ would satisfy $PQ = I_n$.
However, your teacher may have defined $P$ in a certain way, and the order probably matters. Take $E$ a vector space and consider $f$ a linear map from $E$ to $E$, and $C$ and $C'$ two basis of $E$, such that $A = \text{Mat}_C(f)$ and $B = \text{Mat}_{C'}(f)$. Define $P_{C' \to C}$ as the transition matrix from $C'$ to $C$ by $P_{C' \to C} = \text{Mat}_C(C')$. In other words, the columns of $P_{C' \to C}$ are the coordinates of the vectors of $C'$ in the base $C$. Now the order does matter, because $B = P_{C' \to C}^{-1}AP_{C' \to C} \neq P_{C' \to C}AP_{C' \to C}^{-1}$ in most cases.

i think i got it, one last thing i am not entirely sure about.
continuing from your example in the last paragraph, $B = P_{C' \to C}^{-1}AP_{C' \to C} \neq P_{C' \to C}AP_{C' \to C}^{-1}$
the order of $P_{C' \to C}$ and $P_{C' \to C}^{-1}$, since $P_{C' \to C}^{-1} = P_{C \to C'}$ and your example could be written like this as well $B = P_{C \to C'}AP_{C \to C'}^{-1} \neq P_{C \to C'}^{-1}AP_{C \to C'}$ and both C' and C are bases of E how do i know i am working with the correct transition matrix in the right place?

You have to look at the transition matrix and verify that you each column of the transition matrix is the expression of the coordinates of the vector of the basis $C'$ in the basis $C$. If this is the case, then you are working with $P_{C' \to C}$.

In other words, if $C = (c_1, ..., c_n)$ and $C' = (c_1', ..., c_n')$, express $c_i'$ as a linear combination of the element of $C$ : $c_i' = p_{1,i}c_1 + ... + p_{n,i}c_n$. If the transition matrix is $P_{C' \to C}$, the $i$-th column must be $^t\left( p_{1,i} ... p_{n,i} \right)$
